# ORMLite on Android using javax.persistence annotations

Tags: android, persistence, ormlite

We have developed a web service and now are building an Android application to communicate with the web service. We use persistence in our web service and would also like to use persistence in our Android app. We figured that ORMLite was the way to go for persistency on Android and we are hoping that the `javax.persistence` support would be good enough for our app. I was hoping that I would be able to copy the web service's data model to the Android app and not having to modify the annotations.

So I tried copying the model classes and adding `ormlite-android-4.41.jar` and `ormlite-core-4.41.jar` to my Android project. Unfortunately this did not do the trick. My IDE can't find the classpaths for the `javax.persistence` annotations. Do I need additional libraries? I can't anything on that in the [documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.  If the `javax.persistence` annotations aren't in the Android JDK then I'm not sure you should be using them.

That said, if you want to use them, you should be able to get the java files from a JDK source jar and include them in your own project.  Just copy the annotations that you actually use out of the source jar into the appropriate `javax/persistence` path.

The [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) support for the [`javax.persistence` annotations](http://ormlite.com/docs/jpa) is far from perfect.  If you have any problems please let me know so I can improve them.

Comment: I copied the `javax.persistence.jar` to my Android project and that took care of the `javax.persistence` imports. I need to do something similar to get the `javax.xml.bind.annotation`s working. This seems doable according to this article: "[JAXB can be made to run on Android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)", but it is getting to much of a hassle right now. Also knowing the support in ORMLite will not be perfect, I will give up on the idea of using our web service's model 1:1 in our Android app.

Comment: @JasperdeVries this is why i hope google is heavily penalized for cherrypicking java apis for android rather than conforming with oracle's implementation standards

Comment: Proguard has a problem with ormlite android 5.0. Many classes cannot be found, so i added javax as a external lib which is **compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0.2'**

Answer (score 5):

If you are using maven. You can add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively you can download the jar file straight from the maven repository [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0.2/persistence-api-1.0.2.jar) then add it to the classpath. By the way, the `@Table(name = "table_name")` is not supported. You should substitute it with `@Entity(name="table_name")`.